# iText combining rowspan and colspan - PDFPTable

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfptable

Working on a calendar projcet and using iText to generate a pdf to print appointments. I can plot a cell with a colspan, and a cell with a rowspan, but I can't combine it. Table has width of 4 cells. I want to achieve something like this:

(A)(B)(C)(C)

(D)(E)(C)(C)

so  (1,1), (1,2) and (2,1) (2,2) are regular cells. But there should be a cell in (1,3) covering (1,3) (1,4) (2,3) and (2,4) thus having a colspan of 2 AND a rowspan of 2.

Current code:

> PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
>
> PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" 1,1 "));
>
> table.addCell(cell);
>
> cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" 1,2 "));
>
> table.addCell(cell);
>
> PdfPCell cell23 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("multi 1,3 and 1,4"));
>
> cell23.setColspan(2);
>
> cell23.setRowspan(2);
>
> table.addCell(cell23);
>
> cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" 2,1 "));
>
> table.addCell(cell);
>
> cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" 2,2 "));
>
> table.addCell(cell);
>
> // 2,3 and 2,4 should be filled because 1,3 has rowspan 2 and colspan 2.
>
> //table.completeRow(); //no effect

However that generates an error:

> ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.

If i don't start creating the second row, it just plots fine ( 1 row, and cell on (1,3) has a colspan of 2. Since there is no second row, the rowspan(2) has no effect.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first sight, I'd say: you get a "document has no pages" exception because you're not adding any content to the document. I don't see:

```
document.add(table);
```

anywhere in your code snippet.

I have copy/pasted your code into a full example and I posted the full example here: [ColspanRowspan](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/ColspanRowspan). The resulting PDF looks like [this](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/colspan_rowspan.pdf):

[image]

This seems to be the desired behavior. I can only think of two differences: (1) you're forgetting to add the actual table (which was my initial answer), or (2) you are using a mighty old version of iText in which rowspan wasn't fully supported.

Comment: it's just a snippet, I do that later on. As I said if i leave the second row out, there is no issue with the general structure. It's only adding the second row that gives me issues.

Comment: I've updated my answer after writing a Proof of Concept based on your code.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it was the version, since I'm 100% sure about the document.add(table) - I just commented out row 2 in the snippet and then it showed.
Since it was urgent i had to switch to low level API drawing,  but it's nice to see it actually works as I expected.